# Gradle can't create Groovy Map objects inside of a task

Tags: dictionary, object, gradle, groovy

I am trying to create a Map object inside of a task using the following syntax:

```
task newtask{
  newMap = [sname:'a', name:'', buildnr:'', path:'']
}
```

All I get is "Could not set unknown property 'newMap' for task ':newTask' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask." error.

If I try to create the newMap outside of a task, it is created without error. Can someone explain the correct way to use a Map object and ArrayList of Map objects using the Gradle/Groovy syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `def newMap = ...` to declare a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is use a local variable, but what you write is an attempt at assigning `newMap` as if it was known by the current context.

You should change your declaration to be:

```
def newMap = [sname:'a', name:'', buildnr:'', path:'']
```

and then use that `Map` as you see fit to configure the task.